# How to handle Units when Integrating?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, units

I have some functions defined, which are to use units. Now another function is used to integrate over those, with the integration variable also quantified and the input to said function. I better just show some code:
[image: Function Definition]

It's not pretty, but I kinda feel nothing is pretty in Mathematica. I am not very proficient in the Wolfram Language, and I don't have a lot of experience using symbolic expressions.

Back to the code: This will run fine, but when I plug some numbers or variables in, it doesn't work:
[image: First two functions without integration run fine]
[image: First integration function throws errors]
[image: Second integration throws errors]

So, as you see, something is wrong. I have done several hours of research yesterday and I just cannot get it to work. I want to plot this and do some calculations, so nothing fancy, but for this to work, it has to accept inputs like `1 s` and `t s`.

Bonus: I cannot wrap my head around these delayed functions. As you can see, h[x, s, t] evaluates nicely to some easy piecewise function. So why does it take ages and millenia to Plot this? Do I have to do `h[x_, s_, t_] = ...` instead of `:=`? This didn't seem to do anything for me. Also, this is assuming I did not use units, so that the above works.

The Code in Text:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
g = UnitConvert[
   Entity["Planet", "Earth"][EntityProperty["Planet", "Gravity"]]];
TWR[t : Quantity[_, unit_]?(CompatibleUnitQ[#, "Seconds"] &)] := 
 FullSimplify[
  Piecewise[{{0.65 Quantity[1, (1/("Seconds"))]*t, 
     0 Quantity[1, "Seconds"] < t < 
      2.05 Quantity[1, "Seconds"]}, {1.3325, 
     t >= 2.05 Quantity[1, "Seconds"]}}], t \[Element] Reals]
a[t : Quantity[_, unit_]?(CompatibleUnitQ[#, "Seconds"] &)] := 
 FullSimplify[(TWR[t] - 1) g, t \[Element] Reals]
v[t : Quantity[_, unit_]?(CompatibleUnitQ[#, "Seconds"] &)] := 
 FullSimplify[
  Integrate[
   a[Quantity[T, "Seconds"]], {Quantity[T, "Seconds"], 
    Quantity[0, "Seconds"], t}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals], 
  t \[Element] Reals]
h[x_, s_, t : Quantity[_, unit_]?(CompatibleUnitQ[#, "Seconds"] &)] :=
  FullSimplify[
  x Quantity[1, "Meters"] + 
   s Quantity[1, (("Meters")/("Seconds"))]*t + 
   Integrate[
    v[Quantity[c, "Seconds"]], {Quantity[c, "Seconds"], 
     Quantity[0, "Seconds"], t}, 
    Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && c \[Element] Reals], 
  t \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: What is your desired output for, say, a[t s] and a[1 s]?

Comment: Well,@CATrevillian, `a[t s]` is supposed to be `-1g` when `t < 0s` and `0.3325g` when `t > 2.05s` and a linear interpolation between that in between. So `a[1 s]` should be `-3.43m/s^2`, which it is. Also `v[1 s]` does give an acceptable answer, its just that v[t s] does not.